# Setup code for WPF control created in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

Is it possible to see how a control created with XAML could be replicated with code behind? The reason I'm asking is that I would like to create a number of `ListView` controls based on each item in a `Collection`. My hope is that I can setup one `ListView` control in XAML and then somehow get the code that I would need to reproduce more `Listview` objects with the same settings in code-behind.

Alternatively; would it be possible to bind the `Collection` object containing all items that I want represented as `ListView` objects to any control that would then contain `ListView` controls for each item in the bound collection? Just the same way that a `ListView` can create `ListViewItem` controls if you bind a collection to the `ListView` control.

Cheers

Comment: bind your collection to ListView with custom data template containing ListView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a very large hierarchy of controls, I recommend you to do it as follows: You create an List A which contains lists of your data, so A is `List<List<Data>>`

Then you create An `Itemscontrol` which is bound to this list. In the `ItemTemplate`, there is a ListView which its `ItemsSource` is bound to The `DataContext`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not too experienced with WPF. You don't happen to know a tutorial that I can use as a starting point to achieve what you are suggesting?

Comment: I was helped by studying the code from this tutorial. Thank you Alireza for pointing me in the right direction. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/484616/MVVM-Diagram-Designer#Introduction